# Subscribe to NotificationCenter without opening the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm sending notification from the first viewController in a `UITabBarController` to the second viewController in the `UITabBarController` but the second viewController doesn't seem to observe or listen to for the notification until i open it....so basically i have to open the second viewController to subscribe to the Notification the go back to the first one to send it....How can i fix this such that the notification gets to the secondViewController without having to open it to subscribe

Comment: Try with delegates. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/4831524

Comment: Conceptually it would be wise to separate the model logic (where you want to receive the notifications) from the view logic (your controllers, that handle the views), since you can never be sure which controllers are currently alive. Consider ViewControllers a dynamic thing that can be created/deleted on demand.

Comment: To register for notification your view controller must be in memory. Otherwise how you can observe the value change ?. second thing is if both view controller in tabbar controller you can access object of second view controller form tabbar controller and add observer there like `self.tabBarController.viewControllers`

Comment: If you need observer in all of your view controllers Another solution is create one Base ViewController which inherited by all your view controller. Add Observer there on view didload

Answer (score 0):

Make a notification receiving function in SecondViewController

```
 @objc func notified(_ noti : Notification)  {
    print("Recieved fired noti")
}
```

Make a custom class of your `UITabbarController`. In `viewDidLoad` of your `Tabbarcontroller` class write these lines

```
let vc = self.viewControllers![1] as! SecondViewController
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(vc, selector: #selector(vc.notified(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationSample"), object: nil)
```

Here I have taken the index 1 just for example, replace it with your `secondViewController` index in `tabbarController`.

Then post your notification from wherever you want to , just for instance, like from `FirstviewController`

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationSample"), object: nil)
```

In best case scenario, this should work.